# Speed up curl loop in PHP for push notifications

Tags: php, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to PHP, and I'm trying to build a push notifications server

The problem is the curl request loop (2000+ token) is done on almost 5 min, and that's too long, I can't imagine how long it will take if I have 10k token !!

Am I doing something wrong ?

I'm wondering how big compagnies like WhatsApp/Telegram/Gmail which are handling billion of push notifications each seconds are doing to make it fast ?

This is my code:

```
<?

    $context = curl_init();

    if (isset($_POST["pushTitle"])) {
        return preparePushNotif();
    }

    ?><style>
    <?
        include("style.css");
    ?>
    </style>

    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="banner">
        <h1>Notifications</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>
                <label>Title: </label>
                <input class="inputInt" type="text" name="pushTitle" required /><br>
                <label>Message:</label>
                <input class="inputInt" type="text" name="pushBody" required /><br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-block">
        <button type="submit" name="uploadBtn" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

  
    </form>
   <?



function sendAPNS ($pushTitle, $pushBody, $token) {
    if ( defined("CURL_VERSION_HTTP2") && (curl_version()["features"] & CURL_VERSION_HTTP2) !== 0) {
        global $context;
        
        $body ['aps'] = array (
            "alert" => array (
                "title"  => $pushTitle,
                "body" => $pushBody
            ),
            "sound" => "default",
            "badge" => 1
        );

        $headers = array(
            "apns-topic: com.test"
        );

        $sandbox = "https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com";
        $prod    = "https://api.push.apple.com"; 

        $curlconfig = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "$prod/3/device/$token",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
            CURLOPT_SSLCERT => "apns.pem",
            CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => "",
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
        );
        curl_setopt_array($context, $curlconfig);
        
        $res = curl_exec($context);
        if ($res === FALSE) {
            echo "APNS cURL failed: " . curl_error($context) . "<br>";
        }  else {
            $info = curl_getinfo($context);
            echo "ios: " . $info["http_code"] . "<br>";
            if ($info["http_code"] != 200) {
                removeFromDatabase($token);
            }
        }

    } else{
        echo "No HTTP/2 support on client.";
    }
}

function sendFCM ($title, $body, $token) {

    $server_key = 'serverKey';

    global $context;
    $authKey = "key=" . $server_key;
    $payload = [
        'to' => $token,
        'notification' => [
          'title' =>  $title,
          'body' => $body
        ]
      ];
    curl_setopt_array($context, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: " . $authKey,
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "cache-control: no-cache"
            ),
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($context);
    $err = curl_error($context);

    if ($err) {
        echo "Firebase Cloud Messaging cURL Error #:" . $err . "<br>";
        echo $response;
    } else {
        $info = curl_getinfo($context);
        echo "android httpCode: " . $info["http_code"] . "<br>";
        if ($info["http_code"] != 200) {
            removeFromDatabase($token);
        }
    }
}

function preparePushNotif($title, $message) {
    $title = $title;
    $body = $message;

    try {

        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table");

        global $context;

        $start = microtime(true);

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $token = $row["token"];
            if ($row["os"] == "ios") {
               sendAPNS($title, $body, $token);
            } else if ($row["os"] == "android") {
               sendFCM($title, $body, $token);
            } else {
                echo "************ ERROR: unknown device: " . $row["os"];
            }
        }

        curl_close($context);

        echo "Notifications successfully sent in " . gmdate("H:i:s", microtime(true) - $start) . " sec";

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "error pdo exception: " . $e;
    }
}

    function removeFromDatabase ($token) {
        $dbh->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE token = '$token' ");
        echo "*********************************** deleted token $token" . "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: The first thing to do is measure what part of that routine is taking so much time - but you will almost certainly find that the time is lost during the `curl_exec` (but you should confirm). If it is, you will want to run parallel processes for sending the messages, or send a response to the user and THEN send the messages. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php

Comment: if the message is the same for all, then u can pass to sendFCM($title, $body, $tokens) so instead of sending a single token, u can pass array of tokens ['aaa-sss-fff','3gf5-gfds564-gfd', etc...] but i don't know if firebase sets a limit to amount of tokens sent (in firebase i think its 2000 tokens per request) though check more about it, so u can chunk ur token into multi array and each array have 2000 tokens, so if u got 10k tokens, then it should only send 5 requests instead of 10k requests in ur way... and be aware that many requests maybe let u be blocked as spam from firebase...